# Is it possible to use STRING_SPLIT in an ORDER BY clause?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I am trying to order values that are going to be inserted into another table based on their order value from a secondary table. We are migrating old data to a new table with a slightly different structure.

I thought I would be able to accomplish this by using the `string_split` function but I'm not very skilled with `SQL` and so I am running into some issues.

Here is what I have:

```
UPDATE lse
SET Options = a.Options
FROM
    dbo.LessonStepElement as lse
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT
        tbl1.*
        tbl2.Options,
        tbl2.QuestionId
    FROM
        dbo.TrainingQuestionAnswer as tbl1
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            string_agg((CASE
                        WHEN tqa.CorrectAnswer = 1 THEN REPLACE(tqa.AnswerText, tqa.AnswerText, '*' + tqa.AnswerText)
                        ELSE tqa.AnswerText
                        END),
                        char(10)) as Options,
            tq.Id as QuestionId
        FROM
            dbo.TrainingQuestionAnswer as tqa
        INNER JOIN
            dbo.TrainingQuestion as tq
            on tq.Id = tqa.TrainingQuestionId
        INNER JOIN
            dbo.Training as t
            on t.Id = tq.TrainingId        
        WHERE 
            t.IsDeleted = 0
        and tq.IsDeleted = 0
        and tqa.IsDeleted = 0
        GROUP BY
            tq.Id,
            tqa.AnswerDisplayOrder    
        ORDER BY
            (SELECT [Value] FROM STRING_SPLIT((SELECT AnswerDisplayOrder FROM dbo.TrainingQuestion WHERE Id = tmq.Id), ','))
        ) as tbl2
    on tbl1.TrainingQuestionId = tbl2.QuestionId
) a
WHERE
    a.TrainingQuestionId = lse.TrainingQuestionId
```

The `AnswerDisplayOrder` that I am using is just a `nvarchar` comma separated list of the `id`s for the answers to the question.

Here is an example:

I have 3 rows in the TrainingQuestionAnswer table that look like the following.

```
ID      TrainingQuestionId      AnswerText
-------------------------------------------
215     100                     No
218     100                     Yes
220     100                     I'm not sure
```

I have 1 row in the TrainingQuestion table that looks like the following.

```
ID      AnswerDisplayOrder
--------------------------
100     "218,215,220"
```

Now what I am trying to do is when I update the row in the new table with all of the answers combined, the answers will need to be in the correct order which is dependent on the `AnswerDisplayOrder` in the `TrainingQuestion` table. So in essence, the new table would have a row that would look similar to the following.

```
ID     Options
--------------
193    "Yes No I'm not sure"
```

I'm aware that the way I'm trying to do it might not be even possible at all. I am still learning and would just love some advice or guidance on how to make this work. I also know that `string_split` does not guarantee order. I'm open to other suggestions that do guarantee the order as well.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to order by. You have a list with id's, how do those relate to the order? Please share some sample data.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified, the list of ids are ids that belong to the question and the order they are in is the correct order. I will update my post with some sample data soon.

Comment: @HoneyBadger I have added some sample data. Let me know if you're still confused by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified the issue in the question to the following approach, that is a possible solution to your problem. If you want to get the results from the question, you need a splitter, that returns the substrings and the positions of the substrings. `STRING_SPLIT()` is available from SQL Server 2016, but is not an option here, because (as is mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks)) *the output rows might be in any order* and *the order is not guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string*.

But you may try to use a JSON based approach, with a small string manipulation, that transforms answers IDs into a valid JSON array (`218,215,220` into `[218,215,220]`). After that you can easily parse this JSON array with `OPENJSON()` and default schema. The result is a table, with columns `key`, `value` and `type` and the `key` column (again from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-value)) holds *the index of the element in the specified array*.

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE TrainingQuestionId (
   ID int,
   TrainingQuestionId int,
   AnswerText varchar(1000)
)
INSERT INTO TrainingQuestionId 
   (ID, TrainingQuestionId, AnswerText)
VALUES   
   (215, 100, 'No'),
   (218, 100, 'Yes'),
   (220, 100, 'I''m not sure')
CREATE TABLE TrainingQuestion (   
  ID int,
  AnswerDisplayOrder varchar(1000)
)
INSERT INTO TrainingQuestion
   (ID, AnswerDisplayOrder)
VALUES
   (100, '218,215,220')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT tq.ID, oa.Options
FROM TrainingQuestion tq
OUTER APPLY ( 
   SELECT STRING_AGG(tqi.AnswerText, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CONVERT(int, j.[key])) AS Options
   FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('[', tq.AnswerDisplayOrder, ']')) j
   LEFT JOIN TrainingQuestionId tqi ON TRY_CONVERT(int, j.[value]) = tqi.ID 
) oa
```

Result:

```
ID  Options
100 Yes No I'm not sure
```

Notes: You need SQL Server 2017+ to use `STRING_AGG()`. For SQL Server 2016 you need a `FOR XML` to aggregate strings.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I am now able to get the results that I was wanting. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @TrainingQuestionAnswer table
(
ID int,
TrainingQuestionId int,
AnswerText varchar(20)
);

insert into @TrainingQuestionAnswer(ID, TrainingQuestionId, AnswerText)
values(215, 100, 'No'), (218, 100, 'Yes'), (220, 100, 'I''m not sure');

declare @TrainingQuestiontest table
(
testid int identity,
QuestionId int,
AnswerDisplayOrder varchar(200)
);

insert into @TrainingQuestiontest(QuestionId, AnswerDisplayOrder)
values(100, '218,215,220'), (100, '220,218,215'), (100, '215,218');

select *, 
(
   select string_agg(pci.AnswerText, '==') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY pci.pos)
   from
   (
    select a.AnswerText,
         pos = charindex(concat(',', a.ID, ','), concat(',', q.AnswerDisplayOrder,','))
    from @TrainingQuestionAnswer as a
    where a.TrainingQuestionId = q.QuestionId
    and charindex(concat(',', a.ID, ','), concat(',', q.AnswerDisplayOrder,',')) >= 1
   ) as pci
) as TestAnswerText
from @TrainingQuestiontest as q;
```